# UnknownFormatConversionException

Tags: java

I have a homework on studentPoll code. It doesn't work and I always get [UnknownFormatConversionException.](http://javadocs.com/docs/oracle/jdk/7u45/java/util/UnknownFormatConversionException.java) Any ideas? THNX

```
public class studentPoll {
 {
     public static void main( String[]args)
     {
        int[] responses = { 1, 2 , 5, 4, 3 , 5, 2, 1 , 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3,
           2, 3, 3, 2, 14 };

        int [ ] frequency = new int [ 6 ];

        for ( int answer = 0; answer <responses.length; answer++ )
        {
            try
            {
                ++ frequency [responses[answer] ];
            } 
            catch ( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e )
            {
                System.out.println( e );
                System.out.printf( "responses[ %d] = %d\n\n",answer, responses[answer] );
            }
        } 

        System.out.printf( " %s%1 0s\n", "Rating", " Frequency " );

        for ( int rating = 1; rating < frequency.length; rating ++ )
           System.out.printf( "% 6d%10 d\n" , rating, frequency[ rating ] ) ;
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part `"% 6d%10 d\n"` to `"%6d%10d\n"` . You have unacceptable spaces there.

Also, change this part `" %s%1 0s\n"` to just `"%s%s\n"`. Not sure what you intended to do there.